# Grothendieck Constant of a graph and approximation limits

Tags: graph-theory

Let $K(G)$ be the Grothendieck constant of a graph with adjacency matrix $A$. How is $K(G)$ precisely related to approximation limits for some standard NP complete problems such as Chromatic, Independence and Clique number approximation?

Comment: Do you know the survey http://arxiv.org/abs/1108.2464 by Khot and Naor? It seems that you should find answers to your question there.


Comment: This is a good reference. Thankyou.